# Creating HTML5 Video Thumbnail

Tags: html, video

Im trying to make a website using HTML5 and CSS3 but i am having a bit of trouble creating a video thumbnail. What i mean is that i want a thumbnail of a video and when the user clicks it the thumbnail will expand to play the video-similar to this site http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/ - when you click on the "+" the video expands.

If someone could help me or point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please clarify if you want to generate the thumbnails on the serverside (e.g. using php) or on client-side using purely html5 /js/css ?

Comment: @mihai How can one generate the thumbnails using purely HTML5 and Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -an -ss 1:00:00 -r 1 -vframes 1 -f mjpeg -y output.jpg
```

Comment: I think html_noob wants to create the thumbnail using html5 not ffmpeg or other serverside processing

Answer (score 0):

Create a thumbnail from the source video with [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).  There are plenty of tutorials out on the net to do this, like [this one](http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/)